# Angular state with parametes

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to navigate to my state with providing some parameters to it.
Here is my code:

State:

```
a = angular.module('app.panel', []);
a.config(
function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('body.new', {
        url: 'new',
        templateUrl:function($stateParams){
            return 'http://localhost/' + 'new.aspx?panel_id=' +  $stateParams.panel_id
        },
        controller: 'newController'
    });
});
```

I am navigating to this state like this:

```
var url = $state.href('body.new', { parameter: $scope.parameters });
$window.open(url, '_blank');
```

In the state $stateParams is **undefined**. If I am doing it in a wrong way what the correct way might be?

Thanks for help.

Update 1.
I have modified my code to this:

```
url: 'new/:panel_id',
params: {
     parameter: null,
},
```

But my problem is that I am still getting $stateParams **undefined**.

Comment: I can't see `parameter` parameter there in your state.. does it belongs to parent state?

Comment: No, the parameter object should be sent from the controller that opens new page.

Comment: There is no param set up in the url string for that state like `url:"new/:panel_id"`.

Comment: Why can't you use `$state.go('body.new', { parameter: $scope.parameters })` rather than creating the URL?

Comment: Because I need to open a new Browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Just cutting the code down a little bit, it needs altering to this:

```
a.config(
function ($stateProvider, $stateParams) {
  $stateProvider ...
```

It's complaining about $stateParams because you weren't stating it as a dependency.

EDIT:

Or, try this:

```
a.config(
function ($stateProvider, $state) {
  $stateProvider ...
```

Then you could access it via $state.params.id

Comment: Unknown provider: $stateParams

Comment: Updated the reply, try $state instead.

Comment: Unknown provider: $state